# Running a for loop on an ASP page

Tags: php, javascript, curl, asp-classic

I was trying to download the results of a batch and was coding a program for this.

On an aspx file, I was able to write the following PHP code since the URL included the parameters:

```
function get_data($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
for ($i=1; $i<15000; $i++) {
$url = "http://example.com/result.aspx?ClassId=342&TermId=95&StudentId=".$i;
$returned_content = get_data($url);
if (stripos($returned_content,'Roll') !== false) {
echo "Student ID:" . $i;
echo $returned_content;
}
}
```

However, when a result is queried on a .ASP file, the URL simply says 'results.asp' without any additional parameters. Is there a way to use CURL requests to run a for loop and download this data in a similar manner?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try Request.QueryString["name of url parameters"];

Comment: Could you elaborate where I should put that? (there's actually just one number being submitted - 'regno' - to request the result)

Comment: correct me if im wrong. you're going to send URL from a PHP page to ASP right? in ASP,if you don't know the exact name of the parameters that is going to be submitted via URL you can use index instead. this will allow you to dynamically get the values of those parameters. you should put something similar to the get_data() in your ASP page.

Comment: Well, I used the Tamper Data plugin on Firefox, and there's only one parameter being submitted, this is called 'regno' and is a seven digit registration number. However, when I try to go to `http://example.com/result.asp?regno=1234567` (a valid registration number, the result corresponding to which displays otherwise), nothing shows. What could be the problem

Comment: i think the problem here is on the result.asp page. is there a function that will handle the url being requested? i mean do you have a function similar to get_data($url) in ASP format..? i suggest you put it in Page_Load() function so that the debugger will read the parameters being sent from the previous page.